# Tools to Test RPC twisted calls?

Tags: python, django, testing, twisted, twisted.web

Are there any Tools / Chrome plugins like "Advanced REST Plugin" for Chrome that I can use to Test Twisted RPC JSON calls?

Or do I have to write some Python code to do this?

Answer (score 2):

When it comes to testing, you sould always use code, so that if you change something in the future or if you have to fix a bug, testing your changes will be a matter of seconds:

python mytestsuite.py